# Как одновременно взаимодействовать с тремя многомерными массивами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть три многомерных массива с объектами внутри и 4 функций пересчета массива.

```
function fun_1(val_1,val_2,val_3){
return val_1 + val_2 - val_3
}

function fun_2(val_1,val_2,val_3){
return val_1 + val_2 + val_3
}


function fun_3(val_1,val_2,val_3){
return val_1 - val_2 + val_3
}


function fun_4(val_1,val_2,val_3){
return val_1 - val_2 - val_3
}





arr_1 =[
  { x: 20, y: 20, moveTo: true },
  { x: 70, y: 20 },
  { x: 70, y: 40 },
  { curve: {type: "cubic", x1:10, y1:20, x2:30, y2:5},
    x: 3,
    y: 4
  },

  { x: 90, y: 30 },
  { x: 50, y: 30 },
  { x: 50, y: 50 },
  {
    curve: {type: "cubic", x1:50, y1:20, x2:10, y2:4},
    x: 45,
    y: 40
  },
  { x: 40, y: 30 },
  { x: 20, y: 20 }
];






arr_2 =[
  { x: 11, y: 65, moveTo: true },
  { x: 44, y: 43 },
  { x: 70, y: 33 },
  { x: 31, y: 2 },
  { curve: {type: "cubic", x1:10, y1:20, x2:30, y2:5},
      x: 3,
    y: 4
  },
  { x: 530, y: 30 },
  { x: 2, y: 150 },


  { x: 253, y: 233 },
  { x: 212, y: 545 },
  {
      curve: {type: "cubic", x1:50, y1:20, x2:10, y2:4},
    x: 45,
    y: 40
  }
];




arr_3 = [
  { x: 54, y: 123, moveTo: true },
  { x: 44, y: 41 },
  { x: 56, y: 14 },
  { x: 7, y: 2 },

  { x: 11, y: 2 },
  { 
  curve: {type: "cubic", x1:1, y1:4, x2:5, y2:66},
  x: 33,
  y: 11

  },
  { x: 55, y: 33 },


  { x: 66, y: 77 },
  { x: 334, y: 211 },
  {
      curve: {type: "cubic", x1:7, y1:20, x2:5, y2:4},
    x: 45,
    y: 13
  }
];
```

Мне нужно пересчитать весь массив и после создать массив с новыми данными.

Я пытался сделать это таким способом

```
result = []


var type = 1;


$.each(arr_1, function( index, val_1 ) {
result_1 = []


var val_2 = arr_2[index]
var val_3 = arr_3[index] 

//Проверка существования  curve
curve_check_1 = "curve" in val_1;
curve_check_2 = "curve" in val_2;
curve_check_3 = "curve" in val_3;

if (curve_check_1 || curve_check_2 || curve_check_3){
//Подгон
cur = {type: "cubic", x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0}

if((curve_check_3 || curve_check_2) &&  !curve_check_1){
val_1['curve'] = cur;
}else if((curve_check_3 || curve_check_1) &&  !curve_check_2){
val_2['curve'] = cur;
} else if((curve_check_1 || curve_check_2) &&  !curve_check_3){
val_3['curve'] = cur;
}

result_1['curve']= [];

result_1['curve']['type'] = "cubic";

if(type == 1){
result_1['curve']['x1'] = fun_1(val_1['curve']['x1'] , val_1['curve']['x1'], val_1['curve']['x1']);
result_1['curve']['y1'] = fun_1(val_1['curve']['y1'] , val_1['curve']['y1'], val_1['curve']['y1']);
result_1['curve']['x2'] = fun_1(val_1['curve']['x2'] , val_1['curve']['x2'], val_1['curve']['x2']);
result_1['curve']['y2'] = fun_1(val_1['curve']['y2'] , val_1['curve']['y2'], val_1['curve']['y2']);
} else if (type == 2){
result_1['curve']['x1'] = fun_2(val_1['curve']['x1'] , val_1['curve']['x1'], val_1['curve']['x1']);
result_1['curve']['y1'] = fun_2(val_1['curve']['y1'] , val_1['curve']['y1'], val_1['curve']['y1']);
result_1['curve']['x2'] = fun_2(val_1['curve']['x2'] , val_1['curve']['x2'], val_1['curve']['x2']);
result_1['curve']['y2'] = fun_2(val_1['curve']['y2'] , val_1['curve']['y2'], val_1['curve']['y2']);
} else if (type == 3){
result_1['curve']['x1'] = fun_3(val_1['curve']['x1'] , val_1['curve']['x1'], val_1['curve']['x1']);
result_1['curve']['y1'] = fun_3(val_1['curve']['y1'] , val_1['curve']['y1'], val_1['curve']['y1']);
result_1['curve']['x2'] = fun_3(val_1['curve']['x2'] , val_1['curve']['x2'], val_1['curve']['x2']);
result_1['curve']['y2'] = fun_3(val_1['curve']['y2'] , val_1['curve']['y2'], val_1['curve']['y2']);
} else if (type == 4){
result_1['curve']['x1'] = fun_4(val_1['curve']['x1'] , val_1['curve']['x1'], val_1['curve']['x1']);
result_1['curve']['y1'] = fun_4(val_1['curve']['y1'] , val_1['curve']['y1'], val_1['curve']['y1']);
result_1['curve']['x2'] = fun_4(val_1['curve']['x2'] , val_1['curve']['x2'], val_1['curve']['x2']);
result_1['curve']['y2'] = fun_4(val_1['curve']['y2'] , val_1['curve']['y2'], val_1['curve']['y2']);
}

}

if(type == 1){
result_1['x'] = fun_1(val_1['x'] , val_2['x'], val_3['x']);
result_1['y'] = fun_1(val_1['y'] , val_2['y'], val_3['y']);
} else if (type == 2){
result_1['x'] = fun_2(val_1['x'] , val_2['x'], val_3['x']);
result_1['y'] = fun_2(val_1['y'] , val_2['y'], val_3['y']);
} else if (type == 3){
result_1['x'] = fun_3(val_1['x'] , val_2['x'], val_3['x']);
result_1['y'] = fun_3(val_1['y'] , val_2['y'], val_3['y']);
} else if (type == 4){
result_1['x'] = fun_4(val_1['x'] , val_2['x'], val_3['x']);
result_1['y'] = fun_4(val_1['y'] , val_2['y'], val_3['y']);
}




result.push(result_1);






});


console.log(arr_1);

console.log(result);
```

Но почему то у меня ни как не получается сделать это правильно.
Кто нибудь может мне помочь с этим?

Comment: какой массив должен получится?

Comment: @moxolim  такого же формата как arr_1, arr_2, arr_3 но если есть curve в одном из массивов то добавлять  значение {type: "cubic", x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0} пример для  [fun_2](https://ibb.co/kD11YZc)

Comment: мы, конечно, понимаем, что вы в теме и вам ясно о чем вы пишите в вопросе, но для остальных, честно сказать, не ясно ничего, как мне кажется. Все что понятно в вопросе, что у вас есть 4 функции, и есть три массива. На этом все. Объясните логику, как вы вызываете эти функции, и как применяете к элементам массива. Никто тут не будет пытаться разобраться, в ваших попытках написать и отформатировать код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что вам потребуется следующее.
функции ваши переименованы. `pp` -  плюс-плюс, `pm` - плюс-минус и т.д.

текущая функция для операций указывается в переменной `func`.

```js
function pm(a,b,c){ return a + b - c; }
function pp(a,b,c){ return a + b + c; }
function mp(a,b,c){ return a - b + c; }
function mm(a,b,c){ return a - b - c; }


const arr_1 = [{x:20,y:20,moveTo:true},{x:70,y:20},{x:70,y:40},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:10,y1:20,x2:30,y2:5},x:3,y:4},{x:90,y:30},{x:50,y:30},{x:50,y:50},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:50,y1:20,x2:10,y2:4},x:45,y:40},{x:40,y:30},{x:20,y:20}];
const arr_2 = [{x:11,y:65,moveTo:true},{x:44,y:43},{x:70,y:33},{x:31,y:2},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:10,y1:20,x2:30,y2:5},x:3,y:4},{x:530,y:30},{x:2,y:150},{x:253,y:233},{x:212,y:545},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:50,y1:20,x2:10,y2:4},x:45,y:40}];
const arr_3 = [{x:54,y:123,moveTo:true},{x:44,y:41},{x:56,y:14},{x:7,y:2},{x:11,y:2},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:1,y1:4,x2:5,y2:66},x:33,y:11},{x:55,y:33},{x:66,y:77},{x:334,y:211},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:7,y1:20,x2:5,y2:4},x:45,y:13}];


var result = [];
var func = pp;


for(let idx = 0; idx < arr_1.length; idx++){
    const a = arr_1[idx],
          b = arr_2[idx],
          c = arr_3[idx]; 
          
    const curve = a.curve || b.curve || c.curve;         

    var item =  { };   
    
    if(curve){
        const points = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'];
        item.curve = { type: 'cubic' };
       
        let cp = (v,p) => v.curve ? v.curve[p] : 0;
       
        points.forEach(function(p){
            item.curve[p] = func(cp(a,p), cp(b,p), cp(c,p));
        });    
    }
 
    item.x = func(a.x, b.x, c.x);
    item.y = func(a.y, b.y, c.y);
 
    result.push(item);
} 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ахринеть насколько этот код короткий.

Comment: Я заметил что в коде не хватает строки ` if(a.moveTo{item.moveTo=a.moveTo;}`

Comment: @zeni1agent а я в вашем коде что-то тоже не видел ничего про `moveTo`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fun_1(a,b,c){
return a+b-c;
}
function fun_2(a,b,c){
return a+b+c;
}
function fun_3(a,b,c){
return a-b+c;
}
function fun_4(a,b,c){
return a-b-c;
}

var arr_1 =[
 {x:20,y:20,moveTo:true},
 {x:70,y:20},
 {x:70,y:40},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:10,y1:20,x2:30,y2:5},x:3,y:4},
 {x:90,y:30},
 {x:50,y:30},
 {x:50,y:50},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:50,y1:20,x2:10,y2:4},x:45,y:40},
 {x:40,y:30},
 {x:20,y:20}];

var arr_2 =[
 {x:11,y:65,moveTo:true},
 {x:44,y:43},
 {x:70,y:33},
 {x:31,y:2},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:10,y1:20,x2:30,y2:5},x:3,y:4},
 {x:530,y:30},
 {x:2,y:150},
 {x:253,y:233},
 {x:212,y:545},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:50,y1:20,x2:10,y2:4},x:45,y:40}];

var arr_3 = [
 {x:54,y:123,moveTo:true},
 {x:44,y:41},
 {x:56,y:14},
 {x:7,y:2},
 {x:11,y:2},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:1,y1:4,x2:5,y2:66},x:33,y:11},
 {x:55,y:33},
 {x:66,y:77},
 {x:334,y:211},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:7,y1:20,x2:5,y2:4},x:45,y:13}];


var result = [];
var type = 2;

for (var i=0; i<arr_1.length; i++) {//Проверка существования  curve
 if (arr_1[i].curve){
  if (arr_2[i].curve){
   if (arr_3[i].curve){}else{
    arr_3[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
   }
  }else if (arr_3[i].curve){
   arr_2[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  }else{
   arr_2[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
   arr_3[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  }
 }else if (arr_2[i].curve){
  if (arr_3[i].curve){
   arr_1[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  }else{
   arr_1[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
   arr_3[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  }
 }else if (arr_3[i].curve){
  arr_1[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  arr_2[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
 }
}

for (var i=0; i<arr_1.length; i++) {//создание массива
 if (type == 1){
  if (arr_1[i].curve){
   result.push({curve:{type:"cubic",x1:fun_1(arr_1[i].curve.x1,arr_2[i].curve.x1,arr_3[i].curve.x1),y1:fun_1(arr_1[i].curve.y1,arr_2[i].curve.y1,arr_3[i].curve.y1),x2:fun_1(arr_1[i].curve.x2,arr_2[i].curve.x2,arr_3[i].curve.x2),y2:fun_1(arr_1[i].curve.y2,arr_2[i].curve.y2,arr_3[i].curve.y2)},x:fun_1(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_1(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y)});
  }else{
   if(arr_1[i].moveTo){
    result.push({x:fun_1(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_1(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y),moveTo:arr_1[i].moveTo});
   }else{
    result.push({x:fun_1(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_1(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y)});
   }
  }
 }else if (type == 2){
  if (arr_1[i].curve){
   result.push({curve:{type:"cubic",x1:fun_2(arr_1[i].curve.x1,arr_2[i].curve.x1,arr_3[i].curve.x1),y1:fun_2(arr_1[i].curve.y1,arr_2[i].curve.y1,arr_3[i].curve.y1),x2:fun_2(arr_1[i].curve.x2,arr_2[i].curve.x2,arr_3[i].curve.x2),y2:fun_2(arr_1[i].curve.y2,arr_2[i].curve.y2,arr_3[i].curve.y2)},x:fun_2(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_2(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y)});
  }else{
   if(arr_1[i].moveTo){
    result.push({x:fun_2(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_2(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y),moveTo:arr_1[i].moveTo});
   }else{
    result.push({x:fun_2(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_2(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y)});
   }
  }
 }else if (type == 3){
  if (arr_1[i].curve){
   result.push({curve:{type:"cubic",x1:fun_3(arr_1[i].curve.x1,arr_2[i].curve.x1,arr_3[i].curve.x1),y1:fun_3(arr_1[i].curve.y1,arr_2[i].curve.y1,arr_3[i].curve.y1),x2:fun_3(arr_1[i].curve.x2,arr_2[i].curve.x2,arr_3[i].curve.x2),y2:fun_3(arr_1[i].curve.y2,arr_2[i].curve.y2,arr_3[i].curve.y2)},x:fun_3(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_3(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y)});
  }else{
   if(arr_1[i].moveTo){
    result.push({x:fun_3(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_3(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y),moveTo:arr_1[i].moveTo});
   }else{
    result.push({x:fun_3(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_3(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y)});
   }
  }
 }else if (type == 4){
  if (arr_1[i].curve){
   result.push({curve:{type:"cubic",x1:fun_4(arr_1[i].curve.x1,arr_2[i].curve.x1,arr_3[i].curve.x1),y1:fun_4(arr_1[i].curve.y1,arr_2[i].curve.y1,arr_3[i].curve.y1),x2:fun_4(arr_1[i].curve.x2,arr_2[i].curve.x2,arr_3[i].curve.x2),y2:fun_4(arr_1[i].curve.y2,arr_2[i].curve.y2,arr_3[i].curve.y2)},x:fun_4(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_4(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y)});
  }else{
   if(arr_1[i].moveTo){
    result.push({x:fun_4(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_4(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y),moveTo:arr_1[i].moveTo});
   }else{
    result.push({x:fun_4(arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x),y:fun_4(arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y)});
   }
  }
 }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Я немного оптимизировал ваш код под себя.

Answer (score 0):

Код основанный на ответе @moxolim

```js
function fun_1(a,b,c){
return a+b-c;
}
function fun_2(a){
return a[0]+a[1]+a[2];
}
function fun_3(a,b,c){
return a-b+c;
}
function fun_4(a,b,c){
return a-b-c;
}

var arr_1 =[
 {x:20,y:20,moveTo:true},
 {x:70,y:20},
 {x:70,y:40},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:10,y1:20,x2:30,y2:5},x:3,y:4},
 {x:90,y:30},
 {x:50,y:30},
 {x:50,y:50},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:50,y1:20,x2:10,y2:4},x:45,y:40},
 {x:40,y:30},
 {x:20,y:20}];

var arr_2 =[
 {x:11,y:65,moveTo:true},
 {x:44,y:43},
 {x:70,y:33},
 {x:31,y:2},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:10,y1:20,x2:30,y2:5},x:3,y:4},
 {x:530,y:30},
 {x:2,y:150},
 {x:253,y:233},
 {x:212,y:545},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:50,y1:20,x2:10,y2:4},x:45,y:40}];

var arr_3 = [
 {x:54,y:123,moveTo:true},
 {x:44,y:41},
 {x:56,y:14},
 {x:7,y:2},
 {x:11,y:2},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:1,y1:4,x2:5,y2:66},x:33,y:11},
 {x:55,y:33},
 {x:66,y:77},
 {x:334,y:211},
 {curve:{type:"cubic",x1:7,y1:20,x2:5,y2:4},x:45,y:13}];


var result = [];
var type = 2;

for (var i=0; i<arr_1.length; i++) {//Проверка существования  curve
 if (arr_1[i].curve){
  if (arr_2[i].curve){
   if (arr_3[i].curve){}else{
    arr_3[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
   }
  }else if (arr_3[i].curve){
   arr_2[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  }else{
   arr_2[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
   arr_3[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  }
 }else if (arr_2[i].curve){
  if (arr_3[i].curve){
   arr_1[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  }else{
   arr_1[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
   arr_3[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  }
 }else if (arr_3[i].curve){
  arr_1[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
  arr_2[i].curve = {type:"cubic",x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:0};
 }
}

for (var i=0; i<arr_1.length; i++) {//создание массива
var arr_x = [arr_1[i].x,arr_2[i].x,arr_3[i].x];
var arr_y = [arr_1[i].y,arr_2[i].y,arr_3[i].y];
if (type == 1){
var arr_fun_x = fun_1(arr_x);
var arr_fun_y = fun_1(arr_y);
}
else if (type == 2){
var arr_fun_x = fun_2(arr_x);
var arr_fun_y = fun_2(arr_y);
}
else if (type == 3){
var arr_fun_x = fun_3(arr_x);
var arr_fun_y = fun_3(arr_y);
}
else if (type == 4){
var arr_fun_x = fun_4(arr_x);
var arr_fun_y = fun_4(arr_y);
}
if (arr_1[i].curve){
var arr_x1 = [arr_1[i].curve.x1,arr_2[i].curve.x1,arr_3[i].curve.x1];
var arr_y1 = [arr_1[i].curve.y1,arr_2[i].curve.y1,arr_3[i].curve.y1];
var arr_x2 = [arr_1[i].curve.x2,arr_2[i].curve.x2,arr_3[i].curve.x2];
var arr_y2 = [arr_1[i].curve.y2,arr_2[i].curve.y2,arr_3[i].curve.y2];
if (type == 1){
var arr_fun_x1 = fun_1(arr_x1);
var arr_fun_y1 = fun_1(arr_y1);
var arr_fun_x2 = fun_1(arr_x2);
var arr_fun_y2 = fun_1(arr_y2);
}
else if (type == 2){
var arr_fun_x1 = fun_2(arr_x1);
var arr_fun_y1 = fun_2(arr_y1);
var arr_fun_x2 = fun_2(arr_x2);
var arr_fun_y2 = fun_2(arr_y2);
}
else if (type == 3){
var arr_fun_x1 = fun_3(arr_x1);
var arr_fun_y1 = fun_3(arr_y1);
var arr_fun_x2 = fun_3(arr_x2);
var arr_fun_y2 = fun_3(arr_y2);
}
else if (type == 4){
var arr_fun_x1 = fun_4(arr_x1);
var arr_fun_y1 = fun_4(arr_y1);
var arr_fun_x2 = fun_4(arr_x2);
var arr_fun_y2 = fun_4(arr_y2);
}
result.push({curve:{type:"cubic",x1:arr_fun_x1,y1:arr_fun_y1,x2:arr_fun_x2,y2:arr_fun_y2},x:arr_fun_x,y:arr_fun_y});
}else{
if(arr_1[i].moveTo){
result.push({x:arr_fun_x,y:arr_fun_y,moveTo:arr_1[i].moveTo});

}else{
result.push({x:arr_fun_x,y:arr_fun_y});
}
}
}
console.log(result);
```